# How can i set a TREE NODE<T> with two informations-[STRING.INT]?

Tags: java, list, tree

I am writing a program where i have to create a Double linked list full of nodes which user can insert with own values.I have methods to insert the new node into different parts of the list(front, in position,tail). Each node has two informations, one String and the oder INT (both are set by user after creating a new node.
My problem here is how can i set the first information as String, (in the exaple i give there is the version with bot elements INT, but the first one must be string and this is where i need help)

```
    public void insertInFirstPosition(int information,int key) {

    Node n = new Node(information,key, null, null);

    if (head == null) {

        n.setLinkNext(n);

        n.setLinkPrev(n);

        head = n;

        tail = head;

    } else {

        n.setLinkPrev(tail);

        tail.setLinkNext(n);

        head.setLinkPrev(n);

        n.setLinkNext(head);

        head = n;
    }

    size++;
}
```

HERE IS THE NODE CLASS `
public class Node {

```
private int data;

private int informazione;

private Node next, prev;

/* Constructor */

public Node() {
    next = null;

    prev = null;

    data = 0;

    informazione = 0;
}


public Node(int i,int k, Node n, Node p) {

    data = i;

    informazione = k;

    next = n;

    prev = p;

}

/* Function to set link to next node */

public void setLinkNext (Node n) {

    next = n;

}

/* Function to set link to previous node */

public void setLinkPrev(Node p) {

    prev = p;

}

/* Funtion to get link to next node */

public Node getNext() {

    return next;

}

/* Function to get link to previous node */

public Node getPrev() {

    return prev;
}

/* Function to set information to node */

public void setInformazione(int i) {

    informazione = i;

}

/* Function to get data from node */

public int getInformazione() {

    return informazione;

}

/* Function to set data to node */

public void setData(int d) {

    data = d;
}

/* Function to get data from node */
public int getData() {
    return data;
}
```

}`

in this code you can only enter INT values for both of the node slots, the second slot is fine, must be an int, meanwhile the first slot have to be an String. 
Thank all for help.

Comment: Changing the parameter type to `String information`?

Comment: if i do so the second line is all marked as error. thats why i cant figure it out how to do

Comment: Only the first argument may change the type? The second arg is always `int`?

Comment: yes the second argument is int so lets say a number which user can store in. the first one beeing a string can be seen as an description which user gives to the node

Comment: The title tells us that your `Node` is generic but your code doesn't. Please show the `Node` implementation

Comment: i have 3 classes. RUN,NODE, LINKED LIST

Answer (score 2):

You should make your `Node` class generic, and let it accept any class as data.

```
class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> prev;
    Node<T> next;

    public Node (T data, Node<T> prev, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Now you can define a class (let's call it `SomeClass`) that contains all the properties you want to store in a given `Node`, and create a `Node` with:

```
Node<SomeClass> n = new Node<SomeClass>(new SomeClass(information,key), null, null);
```

Comment: i already have the node class, node parameters, as i told i made different methods to insert a new node / count list lenght and so on. My problem is with the first value of the node

Comment: @Artyy Perhaps you should include your Node class in the question, to make your issue clearer. Using a generic Node should allow you to store as many properties as you wish within a single Node.

Comment: okay. i understand what you intention is. i will think about it . thanks

Comment: `T` can be resolved as a custom type. You don't need to restrict yourself to the provided types.